# How to call external javascript from URL inside function

Tags: javascript

I'm will try to make my previous question a little more clearer.

So I have to CPA offer from my CPA network using  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372715"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372716"></script>
```

Now, I want it to randomly call and choose between the two when the user click the download button.

Example scenario:

When a user clicked download button, the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372715"></script>` will be called.

When a new user clicked download again the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372716"></script>` will show.

In ramdom manners.

I hope I make my question clear and you guys can help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to round it up using `Math.round`. `Math.random` will give you a number between `0` and `1`. Rounding it will ensure it will be `0` or `1`. After that you can use it strait in the if statement, because `0` is `false`, and `1` - and everything not `0` actually - is `true`, in case of numbers. By negating you could get `true`/`false` instead: `!(Math.round(Math.random()))`, of course in reverse order, but because it's random, it does not matter. But if that bothers you just add extra `!` to negate it again like: `!!(Math.round(Math.random()))`.

But if you need more than two outcomes, just multiply `Math.random` by the number of outcomes minus one. For example for a three way you could use: `Math.round(Math.random() * 2)`. But then you'll have to use if statement like in your example.

In case you need 1 or 2 as outcomes, just add one to the random number like: `Math.round(Math.random() + 1)`. This will return `1` or `2`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function chose() {

        // Rounding up like: Math.round(Math.random()).
        // Will return 0 or 1.

        // By negating you could get true/false instead:
        // !(Math.round(Math.random()))
        // !0 > true
        // !1 > false

        // For a three way (or more) random switch use:
        // Math.round(Math.random() * [ways - 1]).
        // Will return 0, 1 or 2.

        // For a case where you want 1 or 2 as results:
        // Math.round(Math.random() + 1).
        // Will return 1 or 2.

        return Math.round(Math.random() + 1);
    }

    function GetResult() {
        if ( chose() === 1 ) {
            OfferOne();
        } else { 
            OfferTwo();
        }
    }

    function loadScript ( id ) {
        $('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=' + id +'"></scr'+'ipt>').appendTo(document.head);
    }

    function OfferOne() {
        loadScript(1000000);
    }

    function OfferTwo() {
        loadScript(2000000);
    }
</script>
```

If your code uses `document.write()` and you do not want it to overwrite the whole page if called after `DOMReady`, to be safe put the whole script above into the `<head>`, and use this loadScript function instead, to ensure synchronicity!

```
<script> 
    function loadScript ( id ) {
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=' + id +'"></scr'+'ipt>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great solution about getting random number. But what I'm trying to accomplish is to get random number between 1 and 2. and when I get the number 1, the offer will display the "OfferOne()" function, else it will display the "OfferTwo()" function.

Comment: @RafaelMendoza See updated answer. Last section will give you `1` or `2`, by adding one to the random number before or after rounding it.

Comment: @RafaelMendoza But why? If you do not pass it to the OfferOne function it does not matter at this point if you choose between `0`/`1` or `1`/`2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I already know now to randomly get 1 and 2. I have to figure out now how can I call `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372715"></script>` when I get 1 and `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372716"></script>` when I get 2. Hope you could help me with this one.

Comment: @RafaelMendoza Please see update, using jQuery, a very simple method.

Comment: Thank you very much @rangeOshun. I will try that and tell if that works.

Comment: @RafaelMendoza No! please don't yet :D Your script contains `document.write()`. If you do this after `DOMReady`, it will overwrite your entire page! If it's purposeful, then go ahead, it should work. If not, see added variation of `loadScript()` in answer.

Comment: Great! it works now! Thank you very much @rangeOShun!

Answer (score 1):

Just give your script tag an id and then read the src attribute.
With slice cut of the last character, and add 5 + (0 or 1 random) to the string again. 
So the result will be `372715` or `372716` as the id.

If there is no JS active, the src is still valid, but only with this id: `372715`

***As a side note:*** 
This won't work in your case. The time you manipulate the script src attribute, the script was already loaded. So you should do this on server side.

```js
var dlScr = document.getElementById('dl-script');
dlScr.src = dlScr.src.slice(0, -1) + (5+Math.round(Math.random()));
```

```html
<script id="dl-script" type="text/javascript" src="https://megadownloder.com/script_include.php?id=372715"></script>
```